# How to add content after wrapped text

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

Report generator creates orders in html using absolute positioning to preserve exact layout from report designer.

Order row contains product description and price.
After order row there is horizontal line on other content.
If product description wraps into multiple lines, horisontal line appears between profuct description lines:

[image]

How to fix this so that horizontal line appears after product description. Absolute positioning and hard coded width cannot changed easily, so they should remain.
Is it possible to use inline layout or something else to force div containing horizontal line rendered after previous content?

row class has `position: relative` but for unknow reason horizontal line does not appear after product description.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>

.row {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}

.field-stretch {
  position: absolute;
}

.horizontalline {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.field {
  position: absolute;
}    </style>
</head>

<body>

 <div class='row'>
<div class='field-stretch' style='width:9cm;'>Content wrapped to multiple rows aaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccc</div>
  </div>

  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.5cm'>
<div class='field' style='left:8cm;width:2cm'>186</div>
  </div>

  <div class='row'>
<div style='width:9cm' class='horizontalline'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `horizontalline` to appear underneath. Simply use `position: relative;` with `display: inline-block;` on that class. You can also add a `top` value to clean it up a bit.

```css
.row {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}

.field-stretch {
  position: relative;
}

.horizontalline {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  position: relative;
  /*display: inline-block; for additional spacing betwen content and line */
}

.field {
  position: relative;
}

body > .row:nth-child(1) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='field-stretch' style='width:9cm;'>Content wrapped to multiple rows aaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccc kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</div>
    <div class='field' style='width:2cm'>186</div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div style='width:9cm' class='horizontalline'></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Edit ~** That is ultimately how I would do it. This includes no top values or weird margins. Also, absolute causes problems, especially when trying to look for something responsive based on content. I flexed your first row and added some more text to demonstrate it is filling up the available space. Next, `align-items: center;` will keep the field aligned with the product description, despite how long it gets. Finally, you can uncomment `d-inline-block` under the line to get some spacing. LMK if you have any other questions.

Comment: I removed ´top: .5em´ from css. After that horizontal line is still on top of text. How to put element after text at next row without hard-coded  top value?

Comment: @Andrus So absolute positioning and inline heights and widths cant be changed either? What if I set styles to override those styles using the `!important;` property? Can the order of HTML be changed at all?

Comment: I updated question and added your snipped without top. If running from snippet horizontal line appears  after description. If copied to local html file and opened from Chrome, horizontal line appears between description lines. Layout is created using report designer by drawing boxes and hard coded laues are box dimensions. Those values can corrected by renderer during html creation.

Comment: @Andrus See my edits. That is ultimately how I would do it. This includes no `top` values or weird `margins`. Also, `absolute` causes problems, especially when trying to look for something responsive based on content. I flexed your first row and added some more text to demonstrate it is filling up the available space. Lastly, `align-items: center;` will keep the `field` aligned with the product description, despite how long it gets. You can uncomment `d-inline-block` under the line to get some spacing.  LMK if you have any other questions.